# Relation between emacs and bash terminal shortcuts

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, history

I would like to know what is the relation between emacs and bash terminal shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is too broad however, in bash-emacs mode, cursor navigation is same as keyboard cursor navigation in emacs.

That is

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> will move back a command (recall previous command) in bash, and move on line above in emacs.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> will move backward a char (bash and emacs)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> will move forward a char (bash and emacs)

and so on.

Deletion/Yanking shortcut might work (couldn't test it right now).

Emacs shortcut not related to cursor movement are irrelevant in bash (opening a file<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>)

Bash's [line editing capabilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html) comes from [Readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html), which gives a emacs-like feel by default. Your distribution may also set something else in the system global `/etc/inputrc` or your user's `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: what about CTRL-X CTRL-E to edit the current command line in $VISUAL or $EDITOR?  I assumed that came from emacs too...

Comment: @cas, if you use `set -o vi` then `<Esc>v` opens the current command for editing in `vi`.  But with $EDITOR set to `nano`, `<Esc>v` opens the current command for editing in `nano`.  I thought `<Esc>v` was set in `bind`, but actually I don't see it in the output of `bind -p`, which is odd.  (With `set -o emacs`, `bind -p | grep edit` shows `"\C-x\C-e": edit-and-execute-command`.)

Comment: i know what it does and how the editor is chosen.  i was just commeting that i thought it was another Ctrl-key combination that came from emacs.